# How can you record and access Microsoft Teams meeting audio?

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api, audio-recording, microsoft-teams

I'm working on a project where we need to record and process audio from a Microsoft Teams meeting. The meeting audio needs to be recorded by a bot which is connected to the meeting. The bot triggers audio processing after the meeting ends.

I have looked at using the Graphs API for recording. This API gives a lot of control over calls and meetings, and allows a meeting bot to be created. Specifically, the Graphs API gives access to meeting audio and video streams through `Microsoft.Graph.Communications.Calls.Media`, as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/calls-and-meetings/real-time-media-concepts.

There's just one problem. The documentation states [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Communications.Calls.Media/)

> Note: You may not use this SDK to record or otherwise persist media
>   content from calls or meetings that your bot accesses.

That is a problem because the audio will be persisted, at least until it is processed. Does anyone have a suggestion of an alternative way to record and access meeting audio from a .NET application?

Comment: Could you please take a look at [Call:Record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-record?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) using graph API?

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT Thanks for your comment. The problem with `Call:Record` is that it is limited to 5 minutes. In our solution, we anticipate that recordings will usually need to be longer than that. Is there any way to access a longer recording of the whole Teams meeting audio?

Comment: @OloffBiermann- [Real-time Media Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/calls-and-meetings/real-time-media-concepts) enables bots to send and receive voice and video content frame by frame.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT, the [Nuget Package for Real-time Media Platform](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Communications.Calls.Media/)  states this: *You may not use this SDK to record or otherwise persist media content from calls or meetings that your bot accesses*. So, can we use to record the audio/video, or can we not?